# Apache Gone Down, Can't Restart

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I've recently setup a LAMP (Fedora 18) server to serve a website on a local network. It was all working, then I made a minor change to php.ini, restarted, and it failed. The only thing that had changed since apache was last started was that a DNS entry was added on the network.

```
systemctl status httpd.service
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri, 2013-08-30 09:02:42 BST; 44min ago
     Process: 9769 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful-stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 9767 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/httpd.service

Aug 30 09:02:42 an648robt.parragon.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 30 09:02:42 an648robt.parragon.com httpd[9769]: httpd (no pid file) not running
Aug 30 09:02:42 an648robt.parragon.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Aug 30 09:02:42 an648robt.parragon.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state
```

---

```
# vi /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Fri Aug 30 09:02:42.497697 2013] [suexec:notice] [pid 9767] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 30 09:02:42.568620 2013] [unique_id:alert] [pid 9767] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH01564: unable to find IPv4 address of "an648robt.parragon.com"
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

---

```
# vi /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
192.168.126.200         an648robt@parragon.com bugagon.parragon.com
```

---

```
# vi /etc/hostname
an648robt.parragon.com
```

---

httpd.conf has contained

---

```
ServerName 192.168.126.200
```

---

and

---

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.126.200

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin rich.owen@parragon.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/bugagon
ServerName bugagon.com
ServerAlias www.bugagon.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/bugagon/error_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/bugagon/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

SElinux is disabled, the change in php.ini was just changing SMTP localhost to SMTP and the IP address of the MTA server.  I've changed it back, didn't have any visible effect.

...I'm not a Linux expert, but I've looked at all the forums I can find and I haven't been able to fix the issue. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thanks in advance, Richard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
192.168.126.200         an648robt@parragon.com bugagon.parragon.com
```

Replace "@" with "." :)